# Air mobile app screen scrolling content

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am building a mobile app (iOS and Android) using AS3, Starling and Feathers UI.

Everything works great and the layout is good for iPad. I now require the app to have iPhone support and the interface is a bit tight for room so I would like the screen to be able to scroll to show the entire page/s.

Catch though, I have a header class which contains back buttons, additional information etc and a footer class which contains menu items so the user can navigate around. Some pages allow all the information to fit but others don't (longer pages that require some sort of explanation).

I would only like (if possible) to have the middle content scrollable and leave the header and footer fixed.

```
----------------------------
Header - Fixed
----------------------------



Scrollable content here


----------------------------
Footer - Fixed
----------------------------
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised Feathers UI includes a scrolling content component!